# Append data to a matrix according to a data structure

Tags: arrays, swift

I have the following data structure:

```
struct Books {
    let name: String
    let imagenCover: String
    let volumens: VolumensData

}

struct VolumensData {
    let fileVolumen: [String]?
}

 var dataBooks = [Books]()
dataBooks.append(Books(name: "Tom Sawyer", imagenCover: "sawyer-cover",  volumes: [fileVolumen: "file-1", fileVolumen: "file-2"]))
```

I want to add data to the array, but I have problems with inserting the values of the variable: Volumens.

**What would be the correct syntax to add data of the VolumensData type?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VolumensData` is struct just like `Books` so this can be done like that.

```
dataBooks.append(Books(name: "Tom Sawyer", imagenCover: "sawyer-cover",  volumes: VolumensData.init(fileVolumen: ["file-1","file-2"])))
```